# How to query unique pairs with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the cars collection in firebase with the following format and examples:

```
{
  {
    make: BMW,
    model: X7,
    color: white
  },
  {
    make: BMW,
    model: X7,
    color: white
  },
  {
    make: BMW,
    model: X7,
    color: black
  },
  {
    make: Audi,
    model: Q7,
    color: gray
  }
}
```

What I would like to receive from my query is something like this:

```
[
  {
    make: BMW,
    model: X7,
    colors: [white, black]
  },
  {
    make: Audi,
    model: Q7,
    colors: [gray]
  }
]
```

It doesn't have to be exactly at this format but I hope that I made my purpose clear. How can I achieve this efficiently using firebase?

Firestore screenshot
[image: Firestore screenshot]

My code to receive all the documents:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const db = admin.firestore()

module.exports.getVehicles = async (data, context) => {
  const vehiclesQuery = db.collection('vehicles').get()
  const vehicles = []
  vehiclesQuery.forEach(doc => {
    vehicles.push(doc.data())
  })
  return vehicles
}
```

Comment: You would have to parse that after fetching the data. Can you share a screenshot of your database structure and the code that you are using to fetch it? Can you confirm if the first object is supposed to be an array (since you are fetching documents from a collection) or is that an object as shown?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have edited my question with the information you have asked

Comment: You need to use GroupBy for your vehicles

Comment: @Nirel Firestore is a **NoSQL** database, and doesn't support server-side aggregations, such as group by.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen of course, I meant groupBy those vehicles after getting them from firestore, Like Dharmaraj answer.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to get data in that format. You would have to modify the data using Javascript after fetching all the documents. Also you are missing the `await` before `get()` statement:

```js
module.exports.getVehicles = async (data, context) => {
  const vehiclesQuery = await db.collection('vehicles').get()
  const res = {}

  vehiclesQuery.docs.forEach(doc => {
    const { color, make, model } = doc
    if (!res[make+'-'+model]) {
      res[make+'-'+model] = [color]
    } else {
      res[make+'-'+model].push(color)
    }
  })
  
  const vehicles = []

  Object.entries(res).forEach((v) => {
    const [make, model] = v[0].split('-') 
    vehicles.push({make, model, colors: v[1]})
  })

  console.log(vehicles)
  return vehicles
}
```

Comment: I see so there is no builtin way to achieve this with firebase. This works like wonders. Thank you very much

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı there isn't any at the moment.